magento pwa Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/'
In PWA Venia setup of our website , When we enter all the information under Guest checkout and click on "Continue to shipping method" , it gave below error in console :
Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
I tried below command, but it did not helped me :
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Csp
Response : sku value is not passing

